# limit the width of progress bar in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap to spice up my Ui . I am really inclined to add a progress bar to my page . The following works fine except that the progress bar spans across the entire width of the screen . i would like it to be confined to a small rectangular area rather than the entire length of the screen . Any idea how to do it ?

```
<div class="left" >
    <p> <strong>Use the portal to submit your claims</strong></p>
    <p> Step 1 </p>
    <div class="progress progress-info">
        <div class="bar" style="width: 15%" ></div>
    </div>
    <p> Step 2 </p>
    <div class="progress progress-info">
        <div class="bar" style="width: 30%"></div>
    </div>
    <p> Step 3 </p>
    <div class="progress progress-info">
        <div class="bar" style="width: 45%"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Surely you'd just make the containing DIV with the class of 'left' on it the width you want it to be? If you're using Bootstrap's grid system then you'd use the appropriate 'span' class with a row and a container.

Comment: @BillyMoat I got what you mean .I got it done !  i am new to CSS & html and this is my first webapp . thanks . You may post the above as answer i will accept it :-)

Comment: No worries, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make the containing DIV with the class of 'left' on it the width you want it to be.

If you're using Bootstrap's grid system then you'd use the appropriate 'span' class with a row and a container.

Comment: Thanks! I am a newbie, can you put a line of code here regarding span and row and container or point where I am wrong below: Thanks again
`<div class="container">
  <h3>Step 2 / 8</h3>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 25%">
      <span class="sr-only">25% Complete</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
Renders well in firefox but does not in chrome and edge.